# python,ML: one hot incoder of columns of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding, data-preprocessing

i have 2 colums of pandas, 1 that have arrays of strings and 1 that have arrays of numbers

df=

| row | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['apple','banana'] | [1,2] |
| 1 | ['banana','orange'] | [3,4] |

i want to make one hot incoder to this colums so i wil get df like:

| row | 'apple' | 'banana' | 'orange' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 4 |

any ideas how to do?

i  tried

`from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer df = data[['user_iab_category_ids','user_iab_category_clicks']] mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer() df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Column A']),columns=mlb.classes_))`

but its gives me

| row | 'apple' | 'banana' | 'orange' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: What you want is not according with one hot encoding algorithm. The output of the code is indeed the output expected for ohe.

Comment: ok, so what i need to do so i will get the output i want?

Answer (score 0):

After [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.DataFrame.explode)-ing the cells, [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) will do exactly what you want:

```py
df = (df
      .explode(["Column A", "Column B"])
      .pivot(index="row", 
             columns="Column A", 
             values="Column B")
      .fillna(0)
     )
```

| row | apple | banana | orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 4 |